# Need help in Paginating Hash values in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, pagination

I have the following Hash

```
var messages = { 7 => [m1,m2,m3,m4,m5], 8 => [m1,m2,m3,m4,m5] }
```

Containing User id and a list of messages for that user where the user id is the key and the messages are the values.

I would like to implement a pagination on the Hash `values[Messages]`. 
Can anyone tell me how to implement pagination for such scenario?

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by 'pagination'?

Comment: Is this really a ruby question? `var`? Also, please be more specific and show us what you've tried so far so we can help you.